# Show pasted link text with diacritics not encoded

Tags: block-editor

When I paste following link to the Gutenberg editor and click "create link":

```
https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrol%C3%BDza
```

it remains encoded which is hard to read. Instead, I'd like its text to appear like this:

```
https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrolýza
```

which is the way browser address bar shows it to me (but it turned into the encoded version when I copied it).

Is there some way (e.g. some hook to implement) to customize how links are converted/handled in the editor?

Comment: I could not reproduce this behaviour in the latest Gutenberg plugin when copy pasting your diacritic URL, after converting to a link I could still see a diacritic. Have you tried updating WordPress? Unless you had copied an encoded version? In which case why would it decode the URL? Note that the browser only shows the characters to be helpful, if you copy the URL it will copy the _actual_ URL which has an encoded character in it

Comment: Hey Tom, try opening the url in your browser, copying it from the address bar and then pasting it to the WP. The browser will copy the encoded url, not the "readable" one. What I want is not to "preserve" the same url but to actively do the decoding upon link creation to make it readable.

Comment: There is nothing to preserve, you should not focus on the idea of _keeping_ the diacritic, as it was never there to begin with. Instead decoding URLs on paste is what you need to ask about, which is a very non-trivial thing to do. The number of people who could answer this in the WP community will be in the double digits as it's not an easy thing to do and will very likely require changes to Gutenberg itself, there is no easy snippet for this. Have you opened this as an enhancement/bug on the gutenberg github?